# Rotating a bezier path

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a graphic that describes how to orient a planetary orbit in 3D.  I animate my planet going around in an ellipse on a Bezier curve.

[image]

Next, I want to perform several rotations on the ellipse in space.

What is a simple 30deg x-rotation for the ellipse cylinder object is a -90 x, -30 y and 90 z rotation for the Bezier curve, which it accomplishes at a different rate. In this image you can seem them both rotating, but the Bezier ellipse lagging behind the cylinder.  [image]

Any idea what might be going on and how to fix it so they all rotate together at the same speed?

I'm using Blender 2.79 on Windows 10.

Comment: This really shouldn't happen.. did you apply the transforms of the curve and ellipse at the 0 position, so their local axes are coincident? (..and BTW, it's possible you don't need the cylinder at all, you could just use a filled and extruded  **2D** curve.. the planet could still follow that....)

Comment: everything had their origins at the center of the "Sun" at (0,0,0)

Comment: ..and the local axes were aligned to the world?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why they behave this differently. But you could try parenting you curve to your object by selecting the curve first then the object (with *Shift* held down) and hitting *Ctrl+P* on the keyboard. Then you can animate your cylinder object and the curve will follow automatically.